# update an element of a list

Tags: python, list, element

Say I have a list ["apple", "berry", "cherry", "banana"] .
How do I insert additional info into an element so the list becomes something like
["red apple", "red berry", "red cherry", "red banana"] ?
The idea is that I change the value of an element just by adding something to the element, without having to name the original value.

Regards, slibbe

Comment: `["red " + fruit for fruit in fruit_list]`

Comment: Right, thx. 

Working for me like this even though this may not be the most efficient way to do this.

for i in range(len(fruitlist)):
    fruitlist[i] = "red " + fruitlist[i]

Answer (score 1):

```
**Try this**
original_list = ["apple", "berry", "cherry", "banana"]
    additional_list = "red"
    new_list = [additional_list + " " + fruit for fruit in original_list]
    
    print(new_list)
```